# How to append a class to an anchor tag with wordpress pagination?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, pagination

I'm having some issues with a previous script I was given on here. The script works great, but the problem is I can't seem to figure out how to add a class to the wordpress pagination. Just to be clear, this is for the single post pagination (using ). For the script to work I need to reference this anchor tag. Any ideas how to add a class to this anchor tag?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Gets the query string
var query_string = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?'));

//Appends query string to each pagination link
$('a.pagination-link').each(function () {
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     $(this).attr('href', href + query_string);
});
```

});

Comment: You have to share the code in that "previous script" everytime you ask a new question about it here?

Comment: Fixed that, it doesn't necessarily need to be there for the question to be answered. More interested in just how to add a class to those anchor tags to get this script to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this inside the anonymous function in your.each() loop:

```
$(this).addClass('name-of-your-class');
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with java/jquery, but is that the right thing to do for this? I'm looking to add a class to the pagination anchor tag, and then reference it with this code (where it says a.pagination-link). Currently I don't have a class on that tag, it's just an anchor tag. I'm looking to give that pagination tag an ID/class to be able to reference it with the code above. Again you could be completely correct, not super familiar with it.

Comment: Okay, so right now there is no class on the link and you want to add the class "pagination-link" so that you can select it with the code you posted? In that case target the link using the ID or class of it's parent (so that you don't select ALL links) and do this inside the document ready but BEFORE your code: $('#parent-container a').addClass('pagination-link');

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me. I went ahead and included a screenshot of the inspect element for the part of the page. I used div class linkpagebutton as my parent for the anchor tags. http://d.pr/i/5P3v Thanks!